# How do I create show page based on id of item clicked

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am creating list of items looped through .map function. I want each of these items be rendered in a single page with some other details.

```
import React from 'react'
import {faArrowRight, faMusic, faPlay, faPlayCircle, faTachometerAlt} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import music  from '../mocks/music.json'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import Music from '../pages/music'

const newData = music.map( (data) => {
    return (
        <div className="row no-gutters justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div className="col-auto">
            <button className="btn-gradient btn-circle">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlayCircle} />
            </button>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
            <div className="music-list-content">
                <span className="artist">{data.author}</span>
                 <Link to={`/music/${data.id}`}>{data.title}</Link>
                 
                <span className="play">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} /> {data.duration}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-auto">
            <span className="badge-dark badge">{data.genre}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
})
const membersToRender = music.filter(member => member.id)
const numRows = membersToRender.length
const Musics = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="title">
                <h5>New Music</h5>
                <span>{numRows} new songs</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div className="music-list card-wrapper">
                    {newData}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="footer-wrapper">
                <div>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMusic} />
                    <span>Song Library</span>
                </div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Musics
```

I created a link which whenever I click, it takes me to another page (page not found) with id appended and .js extension.

Please, how do go about it? I want a click on the title and have it displayed on a full page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems good, however, you are missing the most important part, the page creation, since you are not creating the pages, all of your links are broken.

In Gatsby, you have two different ways of creating pages:

- Using `gatsby-node.js` to create pages dynamically: when dealing with a huge amount of data, like your JSON, it's easier to let Gatsby deal with this responsibility of creating pages for Gatsby. Since you are sourcing from a JSON, you need everything set to [create dynamic pages.](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/)

  ```
  const path = require("path")

  // Implement the Gatsby API “createPages”. This is called once the
  // data layer is bootstrapped to let plugins create pages from data.
  exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
     const { createPage } = actions
     const musics= require("./data/mocks/musics.json")

     const musicTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/music-template.js`)

     musics.forEach(music) => {
       createPage({
         path: `/music/${music.slug}`
         component: musicTemplate,
         context: {
           title: music.title,
           description: music.description,
           // and so on for the rest of the fields
         },
       })
     })
  }
  ```

  *Note: I'm assuming that your JSON is properly defined and formatted, having all the fields I queried.*

  Your `musicTemplate` must be a template (inside `/templates` folder).

  Notice that you are passing some fields through Gatsby's context, this means that those fields will be available through `props.pageContext` in your template. So, there, create a template like:

  ```
      import React from "react"
      import Layout from "../components/layout"

     export default function MusicTemplate({pageContext}) {
        return (
          <Layout>
            <div>Hello musician {pageContext.title}</div>
          </Layout>
        )
      }
  ```

  So, as I said, with this approach you are creating dynamic pages based on your JSON file, and they will be available inside `localhost:8000/music/{music.slug}`, and all your reference and links that point there, will be valid.

  I would also recommend using [static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/)/[useStaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) to retrieve data from your JSON in that loop. If you create a static query from that data (in a separate component) you will be able to fetch it on-demand across your project, so you will be reusing an interesting part of logic. It's better to use it rather than requesting a JSON directly.

  You can follow [this guide from the great Jason Lengstorf](https://egghead.io/lessons/gatsby-create-pages-from-json-with-images) which is mostly what you need.
- Adding `.js` files in your `/pages` folder: Gatsby infers the internal structure of your /pages folder and will create pages accordingly to that structure. For instance, if you have a structure like: `/pages/musicians/name1.js` Gatsby will create a page like `localhost:8000/musicians/name1`.

As it has been said, the first approach fits your requirements and it's preferred for this use-cases, since the second one will be less scalable and maintainable.

Comment: Hi, thanks... Please, I want to know if I will need to delete the .map function and replace with the code above or I just need to create Gatsby-node.js and add the code and also create a template file for the other. Meanwhile what I want to achieve is clicking on the title as it is displayed in the code above and then open a separate page with all details fully written for the specific item with corresponding id

Comment: You'll need to remove your code and replace it by the one I've provided. With this approach, you are creating pages in the `gatsby-node.js` and, in any page of your project, you will be able to link to that created page (`/musician/payne`, for example). There, you will be listing all the information of that musician, since it's coded in the template component.

Comment: I used the second approach with my code and everything works perfectly.

Comment: More also, using the second approach, I am planning to have it displayed on current page (above the list), it is displaying pageContext.title undefined.

Comment: Of course, pages doesn't have context until it's provided, the context only works if you are providing it in the `gatsby-node.js` (first approach)

Answer (score 0):

You should do some routing with React-Router (https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic).

So the link have to  point to a Route in a Switch, as is in the example of the link.

Comment: Would be a better answer if you expanded on this and provided an example so your question didn't rely on the link. Also question mentions gstsby so I think it be better to use Link